# Highschool Algebra: $n^2 = 18n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I'm beginning to get into maths outside of school and at the moment I'm refreshing myself on the basics which explains why this question appears to be so simple.

I formulated this equation to find the answer to a question:

$n^2 = 18n$

I then manipulated it to:

$n^2 - 18n = 0$

So this is now a quadratic equation (right?), the problem is that there are 2 solutions.

$(n-6)(n+3) = 0$
$(n-9)(n+2) = 0$

In this case, are both solutions acceptable or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It should be $n(n-18)=0$

Comment: The only solutions are $n=0$ or $n=18$

Comment: $n^2-18n=n(n-18)$. The "solutions" that you mention are not correct. That becomes clear if you work them out (removing brackets).

Comment: Just plug the values (6, –3, 9 and –2) into the original equation and verify if they are actually its solutions.

Comment: Both  solutions  are  unacceptable.  Besides , none   of   the  possible  values  you  get  from  your  two  solutions i.e. $6$,$9$,$-2$,$-3$   can  satisfy  the  equation  $n^{2}-18n$.

Comment: If $n = 0$ then the equation is true. So, $0$ is one solution.
If $n \neq 0$ then you can divide both sides of the equation by $n$. The result is the second solution, $n = 18$. If you know that $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then you can skip the first step.

Comment: May I ask why you didn't think $(n+6)(n-3)=0$ was a solution?  I teach and am always on the hunt for student misconceptions.  I'd appreciate your input. Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, when I was doing $(n-6)(n+3) = 0$ I did think about that(+6, -3) but I thought it would **1.** Just add to the confusion. And to justify myself, **2.** It was the same thing. I basically didn't put much thought into it Karl, thanks :p

Comment: Thanks I'll add it to my list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's your problem:

$$(n-6)(n+3) = n^2 - 6n - 18 \neq n^2 -18n$$

Also

$$(n-9)(n+2) = n^2 - 7n - 18\neq n^2 - 18n$$

However, you can simplify $$n^2-18n =n(n-18)$$

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your mistake is that you've misunderstood factorising quadratic expressions.  You have listed the factor pairs of $18$ and put them into brackets which is incorrect.  Factorising is a bit of an art and takes a little time to get used to but the key fact here is there is no constant term. Usually this hints at taking a factor of $n$ out to give $n(n-18)=0$ I'd advise revising factoring before move on it'll help in the long run.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Definitely did help, I'll make sure to keep on factoring, thanks Karl!

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong

If you expand $(n−6)(n+3)=0$  it will become $n^2-3n-18$

Comment: Tyvm Raj, I understand now :)

Answer (score 1):

$n^2-18n=0\\n\times n-18\times n=0$

so there are $(n-18)$ groups of $n$ and end up with

$n\times(n-18)=0\\ n(n-18)=0$

Now if two numbers multiply to get 0, either the first one or the second one is zero.

$n=0$  or $n-18=0$

$n=0$  or $n=18$

You can always test your solution by substituting back into $n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot MissC, understand now